# Defining the real numbers up to isomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

One of the standard definitions for the real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$, uses the fact that any set $S$ which is a complete, ordered archimedean field, is field- and order-isomorphic to the real numbers. But later on in the study of analysis, at least introductory analysis, the focus seems to shift from viewing $\mathbb{R}$ as an ordered field, to viewing it as a metric space. My question is then if it is possible to define the real numbers up to a bijective isometry without having the field operations defined beforehand? And if this is possible, what about going one step further and asking if we can define $\mathbb{R}$ only in terms of topological properties, up to a homeomorphism?

Comment: The vector space structure gives it more rigidity than just topology I would expect, for example the graph of $\sin(x)$ is homeomorphic to the real line but maybe doesn't uniquely identify it? I'm confused

Comment: @RohanDidmishe, I am not sure I understand your concern, I am not interested in the vector space, field, ring or ordering properties of the real line. I am asking if there is some collection of topological or metric space properties such that if an arbitrary topological space satisfies them, then that space is homeomorphic (or isometric) to the real numbers, since when considering topological spaces, two spaces are seen as "the same" when they are homeomorphic.

Comment: See examples in https://mathoverflow.net/q/76134/11507. Topological space that is regular, locally connected, connected, separable and removing any point leaves exactly two connected components, is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. For metric space - you already need to have real numbers to define what metric space is, so you can as well say "metric space isomorphic to $\mathbb R$". But I think taking standard geometry axioms "there are two points with given distance from this point", "solutions of $\rho(x,y)+\rho(y,z)=\rho(x,z)$ behave like a segment" and so on should be enough.

Comment: @mihaild, thanks! this precisely answers my question

Comment: @mihaild in theory the definition of a metric space only requires the metric to take values in an ordered monoid, right? So if there is a good choice for where all metrics should take values in (we are used to $[0,\infty)$, but a priori it is not clear to me why), we can indeed ask for a characterization of $\Bbb R$ up to isometry